# How can I save songs/audio files to iPhone device iTunes from my App?

Tags: ios, iphone, audio, itunes

I want to ***save/store the Songs/Audio files from my app to the iPhone device iTunes Library***. I have googled and searched in SOF. But, we got it is not possible in iOS. Is there any way to do this? Can anyone please help me?
Looking for your help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[As multiple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5097332/ios-saving-audio-file-visible-in-itunes-library) [related](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/3955/is-it-possible-to-save-http-hosted-mp3-files-directly-onto-an-ipad) [questions state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14902385/how-to-save-mp3-file-in-nsmusicdirectory-in-ios), you can only read items out of the iTunes library.

[The iPod Library Access documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Audio/Conceptual/iPodLibraryAccess_Guide/UsingTheiPodLibrary/UsingTheiPodLibrary.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008765-CH101-SW1) lists no methods for adding or modifying anything outside of what the user controls (and is aware of) within iTunes.